# Cannot acces Port 8443 of my Ubuntu server

Tags: iptables, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I try to connect to my Ubuntu server over port 8443 using nmap.

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE   VERSION
8443/tcp closed https-alt
```

As you can see to the outer world the port 8443 appears to be closed.

However my server lists the port as LISTENING.

netstat -tulpen:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address      State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                 LISTEN      0          18180888    -
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                 LISTEN      0          18180884    -
```

And my iptables Explicitly allow port 8443 before the default Drop:

```
pkts bytes target  prot opt in     out     source               destination

0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I solved the problem. My Domain provider used a proxy to redirect my domain to my server and the proxy blocked the everything except port 80 and 443. Thanks @DeadEye for pointing me to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is listening on IPv6 only. Are you sure your nmap is trying to connect through IPv6 and not IPv4 ?
You can test nmap with IPv6 with the option "nmap -6"

Comment: I get an error from nmap then: `Only ethernet devices can be used for raw scans on Windows, and

"tun0" is not an ethernet device. Use the --unprivileged option

for this scan.

QUITTING!` I'm running it under Windows.

Comment: Also I find my 443 port without the -6 parameter as well: nmap -p 443 -v mysite.net :`PORT    STATE SERVICE

443/tcp open  https`

Comment: Can you test a connection from the localhost ? Can you test the nmap command from a computer in the same subnet ? Do you have some network device between your computer and your server ?

Comment: From localhost I can reach it just tried `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8443` with success.

Comment: And no I don't have a computer in the same subnet. Do you think it could be a problem with my hoster?

Comment: If localhost works and you have the same local network configuration between your port 443 and your port 8443, I don't see what could possibly block you except something between your computer and your server.